# how to generate .apk file for iphone app in xcode 4.3.1

Tags: iphone, apk

Can any one explain me step by step process to create .apk file for iphone app
i am using xcode 4.3.1..am newbie any help will be a great push up for me..
And some explanation about .apk file will be a great help..Thanks in advance..

Comment: WHOA!!! Creating this would be a miracle!

Comment: apk is an android app extension.. for iphone there are .ipa..

Comment: Oh is it..sorry for that i did't know this..Thanks for the quick reply..

Comment: @Suvarna, try to google something like "How to generate ipa file" / "How to generate app file". you will get a some useful links.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 6):

you cant make the .apk file in ios you can make the .ipa file for ios.
see the following steps for creating .ipa file

```
1). you can make the certificate and download provisioning profile in keychain.
2). after downloading provisioning profile double click on that and set the code signing of that.
3). select the ios device.
4). in Product file select archive.
5). in the archive select the Distribution.
6). in radio button second save option select and next
7). select your provisioning profile and next.
8). after where you want to save select your path and save.
```

Comment: ok ok ...Thanks for guidence,and quick reply..

Comment: Can u plz give more details on ur steps?

Answer (score 3):

Its not the APK file that your iPhone app can generate. Its actually called as a build file (.app) that is created using the Xcode IDE./ .ipa file.

The following points gives a rough overview about the whole process.

1. Before creating this .app file certificates and provisioning files should be obtained from the Apple developers a/c ($99)
2. The certificates and provisioning files are used for security reasons to denote that this application is not a hacked one and to make sure its been developed using apple supported technologies only, Its like a digital signature.
3. This provisioing file has to be added with the IDE for that particular project by double clicking the file once downloaded from the developer's site.
4. Each provisioning file will be interlinked with a bundle identifier which is also created using apple developer's account
5. After adding the above mentioned provisioning file, you should add the bundle identfier of that provisioning file into the "Bundle Identifier" key that can be found in Targets -> Summary -> iOS Application target
6. Only after adding this you can integrate the provisioning file to the project (Matching the bundle ID to the appropriate provisioning file).
7. After adding this just issue CMND + B in order to build the application which will create the .app file
8. This .app can be found under "Products" folder that is listed out under the "Projects Navigator" section.

Hope, this would be little risky for you to follow up, since you are newbie to iOS and the above points would give you an overall idea about the .app file in iOS.

Cheers !

Comment: @Suvarna : If you feel that above points satisfies your thoughts. Please accept it.